# Same table in multple schemas

Tags: mysql

New to this, I am creating a database for an application. As the schema is becoming visually complex very rapidly, is it possible/feasable/recommended to have the same user_table in multiple schema?

For example, the blogging schema would have the user_table and the rest of the tables related to this activity. The shopping schema would again have the same user_table and the tables to manage the shopping activity. And so forth....

The objective would be to separata the plenty of tables in different schemas so to simplify the overall managements.

In another post, someone suggested creating a synonym in one the of schemas, referencing the other schema table. Is it the way to go or am I totally misrepresenting problem and solution?

Thank you for your time reading this.

A user table serves two diffent features, each in its own schema:

[image: A user table serves two diffent features, each in its own schema]

Comment: What kind of management do you have in mind that this might simplify? It's better to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing tables between schemas is not directly possible. There's a feature called [federated tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html), which however is not enabled by default and must be enabled at compile time of a MySQL server. So, it's rather not available for your task.

Instead you have only two options:

- Use a single schema to avoid data duplication.
- Use multiple schemas and maintain tables like the user table in each of them in parallel (by executing the same update queries on each of them).